# not enough arguments in call to cli.ContainerCreate

Tags: docker, go, containers

I am trying to run docker from golang and when I tried the code mentioned in the docker official
site, am getting these error. wondering if I have an incorrect vendor

```golang
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx,
        &container.Config{
            Image: imageName,
        },
        nil,
        nil,
        "")


not enough arguments in call to cli.ContainerCreate
    have (context.Context, *container.Config, nil, nil, string)
    want (context.Context, *container.Config, *container.HostConfig, *network.NetworkingConfig, *v1.Platform, string)
```

Comment: You are not passing anything for `*v1.Platform`?

Comment: Try adding `nil` as well for `*v1.Platform`, you typically don't need a value for platform.

Comment: i was wondering what to pass for the *v1.Platform. but passing a nil worked for me. resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx,
  &container.Config{
   Image: imageName,
  },
  nil,
  nil,
  nil,
  "")

Answer (score 0):

In [this example](https://github.com/48d90782/GoPlayground/blob/157b457044f918f97ce61ee2d41f4cbcb57a4f27/docker/images.go), you can see what `*v1.Platform` can be initialized to:

```
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{Hostname: "my-rabbit",
    Image: "rabbitmq:3.7.8-management",
    Tty:   true,
}, &container.HostConfig{RestartPolicy: container.RestartPolicy{Name: "always"}, PortBindings: bindings}, &network.NetworkingConfig{}, "rabbit")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The `&network.NetworkingConfig{}` references [`github.com/docker/docker/api/types/network#NetworkingConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/api/types/network#NetworkingConfig)

> Carries the networking configs specified in the `docker run` and `docker network connect` commands